# Logical OR on one arithmetic and one non-arithmetic condition

Tags: shell

I have little experience with Unix/Linux shell scripting, and none with arithmetic and logical operators. From what I see in documentation, the notation is a nightmare! I've got a simple task to get done and it isn't clear to me which notation will give me the right result, so I figured I'd ask here.

I want to generate a new Kerberos ticket if *either* a certain amount of time has passed since the last one was issued *or* the previous ticket has expired. I could check these separately and run the same code in each case:

```
maxIterations=480 # 4 hours, given a 30-second loop
iteration=0
kinit ... [generate the first Kerberos ticket]
while true
do
  sleep 30 # short-duration loop because in the real application
           # I'm also testing other conditions that could arise at any time,
           # not just whether a new ticket should be issued
  iteration=`expr $iteration + 1`
  if [ $iteration -eq $maxIterations ]
  then
    echo "Requesting new Kerberos ticket"
    kinit ...
  fi
  if ! klist -f -s
  then
    echo "Requesting new Kerberos ticket"
    kinit ...
  fi
  # other checks here
done
```

But, of course, I don't want to duplicate code, so I'd like to know what syntax I can use to "OR" together the arithmetic comparison and the test on the status returned by the call to `klist -f -s`.

Comment: `expr` should never be used in modern scripts -- it's an artifact of the 1970s. Modern (post-1990) shells support `$(( ))` for built-in arithmetic syntax, whereas ksh and bash support `(( ))` syntax as an extension, which enters an arithmetic context without substituting a result.

Comment: Anyhow -- `||` works the same way combining arithmetic and external commands as it works combining any other set of commands. (Particularly when using `[` -- `[` is not special _if_ syntax, it's _just another command_; if the shell didn't have a built-in version as a performance enhancement it would be invoked with `/usr/bin/[`, which is an executable that actually exists on your hard drive).

Comment: Ha. It's so hard to keep track of what information is out there that's been superseded. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smaller change to your existing code is:

```
iteration=$((iteration + 1))
if [ "$iteration" -ge "$maxIterations" ] || ! kinit -f -s; then
```

...but the better approach (if this is really a *bash* script as opposed to a sh script) is:

```
if (( ++iteration >= maxIterations )) || ! kinit -f -s; then
```

Note that the use of `++iteration` in an arithmetic context means you can get rid of the `expr` line above.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post: I realized this isn't bash, I don't know why I thought it was. Just an ordinary shell script, #!/bin/sh.